# TensorFlow: Extension file not found: 'google/protobuf/protobuf.bzl'

Tags: cuda

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.aymeric.net/journal/2016/01/install-tensorflow-with-cuda-3-0-compute-compatibility-devices/) to install GPU-enabled TensorFlow that is compatible with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0.

I installed Java-JDK8, Bazel 0.1.0, TensorFlow 0.6.0, and changed the configurations to run on CUDA Compute Capability 3.0. Everything is good so far.

But when I enter this command:

> $HOME/bin/bazel build -c opt --config=cuda
>   //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer

I see this output:

```
Extracting Bazel installation...
.....
ERROR: /home/me/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1: Extension file not found: 'google/protobuf/protobuf.bzl'.
ERROR: /home/me/tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/BUILD:65:1: error loading package 'tensorflow/core': Extension file not found: 'google/protobuf/protobuf.bzl' and referenced by '//tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer'.
ERROR: Loading failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.006s
```

Any advice?

Comment: Google seems to have quite a lot to say about this e.g. [Mysterious "cannot find .bzl file" error](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/605) - seems like you need to clone the submodule(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed by running this command:

> $ git clone -b 0.6.0 –recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git

Many thanks to @steeldriver for his [suggestion](http://e-not-found-google-protobuf-protobuf-bzl/749696#comment1117567_749682).